# How my app is published on WWW without a Web Server?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, apache, docker, nginx

I'm studing Docker and i just created a Rails app following the guide here https://docs.docker.com/compose/rails/ , the image used in this guide use the PUMA as server APP. When i up my container the app is already published on WWW by myipnumber:3000.

So here is my doubt, how is possible to my app is published on WWW without a Web Server like NGINX/Apache since these are aparenttly not installed in my host or container? (maybe they are but i cant see).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Puma is a rack-compliant application server that handles HTTP requests for you.

You'll need a web server for production deployment (but it's a different story).

Read also

- Rack:  https://rack.github.io/
- Nice explaination by Justin Weiss: https://www.justinweiss.com/articles/a-web-server-vs-an-app-server/
- Comparison or Ruby servers (a bit dated): https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/a-comparison-of-rack-web-servers-for-ruby-web-applications

Comment: Nice explanation of Justin Wess, but PUMA can handle the web requests this is not the role of Nginx? and if PUMA can handle with this why a i need Ngix for production deploy? Maybe i get wrong the Nginx role (i say Nginx but can be any web server).

Comment: Puma role is to host your ruby web application - transform HTTP to ruby data structures and back, manage threads/processes etc. Nginx takes care of caching, handling static files, SSL, traffic limiting.

Comment: So Nginx help me to control the requests, but i still dont understand why i must have this for production

Comment: [Nginx page](https://www.nginx.com/resources/glossary/application-server-vs-web-server/) | [Quora thread](https://www.quora.com/Why-do-we-need-to-put-our-web-server-applications-behind-other-web-servers-like-Apache-and-NGINX-Whats-the-point-Do-they-primarily-serve-as-load-balancers) | [Server fault question](https://serverfault.com/questions/605853/what-is-thin-and-why-do-i-need-it)

Comment: Now much things have sense, but i have a last question. how my docker container with nginx as server, communicate with host? cause if i get a request on my host ip how this is handled to container?

Comment: You have a docker container with puma and nginx on the host? You need to configure reverse proxy on nginx and use good old TCP sockets to communicate with puma (you need to expose a port from docker).